# What is the principle of IntelliJ IDEA's remote debug?

Tags: intellij-idea, remote-debugging

It's easy to debug remotely in Intellij IDEA, but what is the principle? In what way does the IDEA catch the request?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/